# Aligning RGB and Depth Images using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to align an RGB Image and Depth Map so that I can find the depth of a particular point on the RGB Image. These images are taken on the Magic Leap 2, which has a depth camera and an RGB camera. For both of the images I have the camera intrinsics, distortion coefficients, and FOV. Assuming I also have the translational and rotational relationship between the two cameras as well, how can I use OpenCV in python to align these two images (what's the pipeline of OpenCV functions I need to use?). I've already undistorted both images using the intrinsics and distortion coefficients, as well as crop the depth image based on its FOV to make a better match to the RGB image, but the two images don't match perfectly in all areas of the image.

Comment: you can just transform the point cloud into one of the color eyes' coordinate frame, using nominal values (distances between cameras). calibration would be better. this amounts to a change of viewpoint. you will get "holes" in the depth map because you're working with the point cloud, that you would project again, after transformation. -- is that depth camera IR-based? then you can prepare a calibration target that has well locatable points that are visible in IR and color

Answer (score 0):

You need to go step by step and check what is the exact issue:

1. Calibrate them independently - cv2.calibrateCamera()
2. Undistort images - cv2.undistort()
3. Try stereo calibration (If you have multiple images from both cameras of a known pattern (like chessboard), use cv2.stereoCalibrate() to find the rotational differences Then try - cv2.stereoRectify(),  cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap() and cv2.remap()
4. Align the images via feature matching with cv2.ORB_create() to find keypoints and cv2.BFMatcher to match them. You can use
   cv2.findHomography() and cv2.warpPerspective() to warp them as each other.